# childColumnStatic is undefined

Tags: spservices

I am getting the error "childColumnStatic"  is undefined .

I am trying to implement cascading dropdown using the below code.  Here the column "profilesystem" contains more than 20 items. The below code works fine if the number of columns is less than 20 items but for different item.

```
  $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList:"Unit",
    relationshipListParentColumn:"profilesystem",
    relationshipListChildColumn:"Unit",
    parentColumn:"ProfileSystem",
    childColumn:"Profile_x0020_Unit"
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

childColumn should be the DisplayName of the column in the form, not the StaticName. Since you were using "Profile_x0020_Unit", it was undoubtedly the StaticName (we rarely name our columns with encoded characters). This is noted in the documentation. Let me know if it isn't clear somehow and how I can update it if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

It started working after i renamed the chilColumn from "Profile_x0020_Unit " to ProfileUnit... When i opened the Jquery i found that childColumnstatic is nothing but getting the attr of "childColumn" so thought there is something wrong with ChildColumn and changed its title.

Hope it helps someone in future